# Response.Redirect("url") Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, redirect, response.redirect

In C# using visual studio 2010 .NET framework 4.0.

Every time I try to make a redirection using `response.redirect("url")` I get the following error:

```
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=App_Web_uck3gvsb
  StackTrace:
       at _Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\p1\Default.aspx.cs:line 15
       at System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e)
       at System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e)
       at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
       at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
       at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
  InnerException:
```

And here is the code: Even on simple without anything, I get the same error!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public  HttpResponse response;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        response.Redirect("http://www.google.com");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be using:

```
Response.Redirect("www.bing.com");
```

not:

```
response.Redirect("...")
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to utilize the [Page.Response](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.response.aspx) property:

```
Page.Response.Redirect(...);
```

or just

```
Response.Redirect(...);
```

When you declare your `HttpResponse` object it is not initialized and hence `null`. This is the reason for the exception.

Comment: i get the following error once i use it directly as you mention !Response is not available in this context.

Comment: There's no need to declare a `HttpResonse` object. ASP.NET does that for you in the Page object. Remove the declaration of `response`.

Answer (score 2):

Comment out your `public  HttpResponse response;` You have declared an `unnecessary` variable which is not initialised.

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    //public  HttpResponse response;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //this is enough
        Response.Redirect("http://www.google.com");
    }
}
```